# Accessing kendo grid cell values

Tags: jquery, checkbox, typescript, kendo-grid

I have an web application that uses Kendo Grid. How would I obtain the values of "Ticket No" of the selected check-boxes?

[image]

My code is:

```
var grid = $("#poGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.items().filter(":has(:checked)").each(function () {
    var tr = $(this);
    console.log(grid.dataItem(tr));
    console.log("Length => " + grid.dataItem(tr.length.toString()));
});

console.log(" grid.items().length => " + grid.items().length);
console.log(" grid.dataItem.ticketNumber => " + grid.dataItem.ticketNumber);
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
grid.items().filter(":has(:checked)").each(function () {
  var tr = $(this);

  // Current data item
  var dataItem = grid.dataItem(tr);
  console.log(dataItem);

  // Access the ticketNumber
  var ticketNumber = dataitem.ticketNumber;
  console.log("ticketNumber=> " + ticketNumber );
});
```